# Dative single noun Bankautomaten?

Tags: noun, dative

I could not understand why it is Bankautomat**en** in this sentence

```
Kannst du an einem Bankautomat**en** anhalten?
```

In the dictionary, the singular noun is Der Bankautomat and plural noun is Die Bankautomat**en**. Why can it be *einem Bankautomat**en***? What is the grammar rule here?

Comment: What would you expect instead?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ clearly the OP would expect *Bankautomat*.

Comment: You have to consider all hints: *einem Bankautomat**en*** cannot be plural because *ein* is a strictly singular article. The *-em* at *einem* gives away it's dative case, and the *-en* on *Bankautomaten* agrees to that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a group of nouns called n-stem, or weak nouns. These nouns take a weak "-en" ending in the genitive, dative and accusative singular forms. *Der Automat* belongs to this group.

Examples include:

> Der Junge, des Jungen, dem Jungen, den Jungen
>   Der Kunde, des Kunden, dem Kunden, den Kunden
>   Der Bär, des Bären, dem Bären, den Bären
>   Der Mensch, des Menschen, dem Menschen, den Menschen

There is also a (very) small subgroup in which the singular genitive takes "-ens" as an ending:

> Der Name, des Namens, dem Namen, den Namen
>   Das Herz, des Herzens, dem Herzen, das Herz *
>   Der Wille, des Willens, dem Willen, den Willen
>   Der Gedanke, des Gedankens, dem Gedanken, den Gedanken

** Note the accusative form for Herz*

Comment: But note that in south-German dialects, in spoken language, the dative -en is often omitted. Dem Junge, dem Kunde, dem Bär, dem Mensch is what I and people around me would say - not write, though.

Answer (score 4):

Because the word "an" in this usage requires a dative, and (Bank)automaten is a dative singular form (and also the dative plural form).

Comment: The preposition "an" can also be used with accusative, but not in this case because *anhalten* does not involve direction.

Comment: *Bankautomaten* matches all cases except nominative singular. One has to check the article to determine the case.